# Why is there an error for a character limit of 255 on text field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

After finding 2 SO questions related to string vs. text fields, I discovered that the link field ***is already*** text:

```
create_table "answers", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "text"
  t.text     "link"
```

Why is Postgres throwing the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)
```

I tried a migration `change_column :answers, :link, :text, :limit => nil` but I don't think that does anything.

Edit: So, the problem is that the schema says the field is text, but actually it is string:

```
Answer.new.column_for_attribute('link').type
=> :string
```

What is the best way to fix it? By rebuilding the database from the schema? By changing it to string and then back to text?

Rails 3.2.2, Postgres 9, Heroku.

Comment: Just my $0.02, but I avoid writing my Rails migrations using the somewhat cryptic `create_table` and friends. I just execute the appropriate statements for PostgreSQL/MySQL. I want to know exactly what my schema looks like (types, indexes, constraints etc).

Comment: Since a `text` column has no limit, and `character` and `character varying` have limits of 1 and nothing respectively by default in PostgreSQL, the code creating the table must be explicitly specifying a limit of 255. Thus, PostgreSQL is working as intended.

Comment: Sure it's not the column named "text" that's an issue? I'd connect to the db through some other means (psql) to verify that things are as you think. Migrations tend to be well behaved in my experience. Perhaps the migration was changed after you ran it?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about "text". That was also a good possibility.

Comment: The best thing to do is to forget that `t.string` exists when using PostgreSQL, just use `t.text` everywhere. `varchar` is a an anachronism in PostgreSQL so don't bother with it unless you have a need for a specific size of string.

Comment: @d11wtq: That's heresy! But my kind of heresy :) Next you'll be saying crazy things like "foreign keys in the database are a good idea", "check constraints are wonderful", and "some logic belongs in the database".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure how it happened, but one of the following:

1. I checked the schema after running the migration, so actually it was in sync.
2. I ran a migration to change the type to string, bringing the schema in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Write your migration using raw SQL statements sent to Postgres. Just call `execute` with whatever you'd run directly in the psql console. It's the best way to know exactly what state your DB is going to be left in. Often this is a better solution than letting Rails define your schema for you. You should really look at your schema regularly, especially after running a migration.